# Insert in If Else in Foreach Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, joomla, foreach

Question: to insert $Current when $Current is not match with all $subs.

```
foreach ($array1 as $index=>$Current){
        foreach ($array2 as $key=>$subs){
            echo "\nCurrent: ".$Current; //get current 
            echo "\nsubs: ".$subs; //get subs
            if ($Current== $subs){
                echo "\n++++++\n";
            } else{
                echo "\n=====\n";
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `#__table` (user_id, cat_id, subs) VALUES (".$userid.",".$other_array [$index].",".$Current.")";
                echo "\n".$sql;
            }
        }

    }
```

The actual output are:

```
Current: 1
subs: 9
=====

INSERT INTO `#__table` (user_id, cat_id, subs) VALUES (1,1,1)
Current: 1
subs: 11
=====

INSERT INTO `#__table` (user_id, cat_id, subs) VALUES (1,1,1)
Current: 1
Subs: 1
+++++
```

My expected output should be execute Insert sql after comparing current and subs are different. which is likely like:

```
Current: 1
subs: 9
=====

Current: 1
subs: 11
=====

Current: 1
Subs: 1
+++++

// EXECUTE THIS AFTER COMPARING ALL Current and subs *** 
INSERT INTO `#__table` (user_id, cat_id, subs) VALUES (1,1,Current)
```

So how should I write for the foreach loop? Or shouldn't I use foreach?

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You may want to rethink your question a little, I have no idea what you're asking. Why is that the expected output?

Comment: @castis I need to execute insert sql after done all comparison of 2 arrays. if follow the actual output, then it will insert the same record many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to loop through $Current, and if $Current does not exist in $subs, you want it to insert into the database.

Try using the `in_array` function, like this:

```
foreach ($array1 as $index=>$Current){
    if (!in_array($Current, $array2))
        echo "\n=====\n";
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `#__table` (user_id, cat_id, subs) VALUES (".$userid.",".$other_array [$index].",".$Current.")";
        echo "\n".$sql;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought I had interpreted the question correctly. To clarify, you want it to loop through all of the $Current and all of the $subs, and if it finds a match, do a single insert at the very end?

Comment: I want is loop through $Current and all $subs, if match->do nothing; else-> insert $Current at the very end. you may refer to my expected output, I compare $Current to all $subs, at the end I insert $Current.

Comment: You'll find that if you loop through $array2, it will ALWAYS find an instance where there is no match (assuming $array1 or $array2 have more than one value). Try use the `in_array` function. I've edited the post to use in_array.